# Regex: access to nested matches with limit quantifier

Tags: regex, string, replace

So my regular expression is:

```
((('.*'),(\n)){2})
```

And my subject is

```
'Welcome',
'to',
'RegExr',
'to',
'sad',
```

So I want to get

```
'Welcome','to',
'RegExr','to',
'sad',
```

How can I do this? If I just write `$2` it gives me `'to''to''sad'`, but not `'Welcome''to''RegExr''to''sad'` - first; second (the most important I think) - ***how can I access to each of `{2}` these subjects?***

Comment: The most important question here is, which regex engine are you using? Also, give more context about your task. It's likely that your way to think about it is not the only way to think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Two line shrinking scenario

You may use

```
\n(.*(?:\n|$))
```

and replace with `$1`. If there can be CR before LF, use

```
\r?\n(.*(?:\r?\n|$))
```

where `\r?\n` matches an optional CR abd then LF. Note that to match the major three line break types, you may replace `\r?\n` with `(?:\r\n?|\n)`. Alternatively, if `\R` (any line break) construct is supported:

```
\R(.*(?:\R|$))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Kv2ck/1)

**Details**:

- `\n` - a newline
- `(.*(?:\n|$))` - Group 1 capturing any 0+ chars other than line break (`.*`)  up to and including a newline or the end of string (`$`).

## Shrinking arbitrary number of lines

You may use a regex to match 5 lines [like this](https://regex101.com/r/n73Fh0/2):

```
'.*',(?:\r?\n'.*',){4}
```

And then inside a match evaluator/callback function (method) remove all line breaks.

See a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/faVaom):

```
$s = "'text 1',\n'text 2',\n'text 3',\n'text 4',\n'text 5',\n'text 6',\n'text 7',\n'text 8',\n'text 9',\n'text 10',\n'MORE here'\n";
$lines_to_shrink = 5;
echo preg_replace_callback("~'.*',(?:\R'.*',){" . ($lines_to_shrink-1) . "}~", function($m) {
    return str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), "", $m[0]);
}, $s);
```

Output:

```
'text 1','text 2','text 3','text 4','text 5',
'text 6','text 7','text 8','text 9','text 10',
'MORE here'
```

Comment: Ok, but if I have more than 2? 5, 10, 15 - doesn't matter?

Comment: The same example, but ((('.*'),(\n)){5`or 10 or 15`})

Comment: @Nikita_kharkov_ua: There is no way to do it the way you want with a mere regex. What is the programming language? See my update, Scenario #2.

Comment: Thanks a lot for full-dress answer! :)